# List is getting filtered without using it directly

Tags: jquery

This is the code below:

```
OnChangePaymentMode: function (mode) {
    var Data = [];
    Data = QuickJV.FormOperations.List;
    if (Data != null) {
        if (mode != "All") {
            for (var i = 0; i < Data.receiptList.length; i++) {
                Data.receiptList[i].paymentModeList = Data.receiptList[i].paymentModeList.filter(function (el, i) {
                    return (el.paymentMode == mode);
                });
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < Data.paymentList.length; i++) {
                Data.paymentList[i].paymentModeList = Data.paymentList[i].paymentModeList.filter(function (el, i) {
                    return (el.paymentMode == mode);
                });
            }
        }
        QuickJV.FormOperations.CreateRowDataForReceiptAndPayment(Data);
    }
}
```

I am using jquery filter on "Data" variable but still my `QuickJV.FormOperations.List` data is getting filtered which is my main List.

Comment: because, in the 3rd line, you point Data to your main List, so they're the same thing.   You need to copy or clone the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(QuickJV.FormOperations.List));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You need to clone the array. Otherwise it will be a reference type, so all the changes will be reflected in main array.

Change this

```
var Data = [];
Data = QuickJV.FormOperations.List;
```

To

```
var Data = [];
Data = QuickJV.slice();
Data=Data.FormOperations.List;
```

Comment: QuickJV.FormOperations.List.clone is not a function

Comment: Sorry sir, i am getting same error that slice is not a function